# MySQL many-to many relationship

Tags: mysql

Can't create the last table:( It seems to me that the answer should be very simple, but unfortunately can't find it.
Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Topics ( topicId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        topicName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        submdate DATE NOT NULL,
        accdate DATE NOT NULL, 
        comm VARCHAR(100), 
        status varchar(1) CHECK (status>0 and status<4),
        PRIMARY KEY (topicId) );


CREATE TABLE Student ( studentId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        studentname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (studentId) );  


CREATE TABLE TopicStudent ( topicId INT NOT NULL,
            studentId INT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (topicId, studentId),
            CONSTRAINT Constr_TopicStudent_Student_fk
                FOREIGN KEY Student_fk (studentId) REFERENCES Student (studentId)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
            CONSTRAINT Constr_TopicStudent_Topic_fk
                FOREIGN KEY Topic_fk (topicId) REFERENCES Topic (topicId)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            );
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that      corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Const     r_TopicStudent_Student_fk FOREIGN KEY Student_fk (studentId) REFERENCES Stu' at      line 1

Answer (score 0):

`Const r_TopicStudent`? Is there a blank space between "Const" and "r_TopicStudent"?

Comment: there isn't any space